# Can I save a text element using Cypress, and then use its text as an input?

Tags: cypress

I'd like to get an element on my page, save its text, and then later type that same text into a text input element as part of a single spec. type() only accepts strings. Is there an accepted workaround, or is this a case of not knowing the best practice?

```
cy.get(".navbar-text").then(($user) => {
      const user = $user.text;
      cy.get(".historySearch").type($user.text); 
      //.type(user) and .type($user.text) both cause errors on the previous line
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery for text extract is a function, use it with Cypress `invoke` command

```js
cy.get('.navbar-text.)
  .invoke('text')
  .then(user => {
    cy.get(".historySearch").type(user); 
  });
```

or directly like this

```js
cy.get(".navbar-text")
  .then($user => {
    const user = $user.text()
    cy.get(".historySearch").type(user)
  });
```

Comment: This works nicely. I used the second example you gave, my mistake was simply forgetting the empty parentheses on $user.text() This caused an error message which appeared to be related to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases) `.as()` to save the inner text value and use it later.

```js
cy.get('.navbar-text').invoke('text').as('navbarText')
cy.get('@navbarText').then((text) => {
   cy.get('.historySearch').type(text);
})
```